Laravel, how to implement the model resolution between jobs like we do in Routing?
I have a job that is called by another job or a controller. Let's call it CalledJob.
The calling job should be able to pass just the ID of the model and the CalledJob constructor/handle should receive the instantiated model instance.
CallinJob 

{

function handle(){

$user = User::where('name','John')->first();

CalledJob:dispath($user->id); // passed only the user id

}

}

CalledJob 


{

Private User $user;

function __construct(User $user)

{

$this->user = $user; // received the user instance instead of id

function handle(){ 

print $this->user->name; 

}

}

I have tried to use SerializeModel but not sure. Laravel should be able to do this because it does something similar (if not same) while routing where passing ID in request, instantiates a model instance.

There's a trait called SerializesModels (it's shown in the docs. It doesn't explicitly say what it does but it can be inferred from its name). If you use this then all your model properties should get properly serialized and unserialized between queuing and processing the job

As said in the description, I've tried that. SerializeModels does not help with this. It only serializes the model for correct passing to another job/class. It doesn't convert the ID back to model instance.

I think I misunderstood the problem. Laravel will not populate the model from the given id for queued jobs. It only does that in controller routes.  You can pass the model instance itself to the job so there is no reason for you to need this behaviour anyway
